# How do scanf and printf work with a while loop?

Tags: c

I read input from the keyboard using `scanf()` in a `while` loop and print back on the screen using `printf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char ch;

    printf("enter your name");

    while(ch!='/n')
    {
         scanf("%c",&ch);
         printf("%c",ch);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I want to know how `printf()` prints the value on screen, because when the user presses the <kbd>enter</kbd> key, the program is out of the loop.

Comment: I think the poster means `'\n'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a good idea to check the value of `ch` (in `while` loop) before assigning it a value.

- First before entering loop, it checks whether `ch` equals `"\n"` which it does not (hopefully).

  ```
  while(ch!='/n')
  ```
- It enters the loop. `scanf()` executes, waits for input. Suppose, you enter `"a"` and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

  ```
  scanf("%c",&ch);
  ```
- As a whitespace character is encountered, it continues to next line, which prints the character entered earlier.
- Then you check again: this time `ch==a`, so it enters the loop again.
- Now, `scanf()` is executed again, the input buffer already has `"\n"`, it is read.

  ```
  scanf("%c",&ch); //This time INPUT BUFFER already has "\n"
                   //so it wont ask for user input.
  ```
- `"\n"` read earlier, gets printed.
- Now, `ch == "\n"`, so the loop exits.

The catch was that even though your read `"a"` from the input, the input buffer already had `"\n"` the second time the loop was executed. To avoid situations like that you should use

```
scanf("%c\n", &ch)
```

Answer (score 0):

The user needs to print "\n" before scanf will return.

It's called "[buffered I/O](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/)".

The final "getchar()" just keeps the program from exiting before you've had a chance to see the results.  This would be important, for example, if your program is running from a Windows command prompt, and the command prompt disappears as soon as the program exits.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` doesn't input the hole line. It only inputs until a space character is found (i.e. `'\n'` or `' '`). The input process begins after ENTER key is pressed. It continues input unitl it finds a white character. Take this example:

input:

```
h s a e f o w 2 4 ; f e e
*Then ENTER-KEY was pressed)
```

Output:

```
h s a e f o w 2 4 ; f e e
```

If we are inputing strings, it wont' get the hole line, but a word by word:

**input:** (using `scanf("%s", &str)`):

```
Hello World C language!
(Then ENTER-KEY was pressed)
```

**Output:** (using `printf("%s\n", str)`):

```
Hello
World
C
Language!
```

Comment: To be accurate, scanf() stops when you reach a whitespace charater.